# Supremum of absolute value of Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

I know that by the reflection principle,
$$
P\left[\sup_{0 < s < t} B_s > a \right] = 2P[B_t> a]
$$
where $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion. But what is $P\left[\sup_{0 < s < t} |B_s|> a \right]$?

Comment: Hint: $B_t$ has the same distribution as $-B_t$ and $P(\sup_{0 < s < t} |B_s| > a) = P(\sup_{0 < s < t}B_t > a$ or $\inf_{0 < s < t} B_t < -a)$. Use a union bound--for your previous question, you just need to bound this probability, you do not need to know the probability exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Phi_t(x)$ be the cdf for $B_t$. Then
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sup_{0< s< t} |B_s|\le a\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^k\Big(\Phi_t\big(a(2k+1)\big)-\Phi_t\big(a(2k-1)\big)\Big).
$$

Comment: Nice! How do you prove this?  Also, do you know a way to lower bound this for large $t$?

Comment: @ThomasAhle [Here's my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3688726/177399). Since the terms decrease in absolute value as $k\to \pm\infty$, you get a lower bound by taking only the $k=-1,0,1$ terms. That is, $P(\sup |B_s|\le a)\ge -\Phi(3a)+2\Phi(a)-2\Phi(-a)+\Phi(-3a)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in the case $a$ constant and $t$ large, (same as $a\to 0$ and $t=1$). It seems I need at least $t$ terms of the sum for the lower bound to still be meaningful ($> 0$). Ideally, I'm hoping for a bound like $\Pr(\sup_{0<s<t}|B_s|\le a) \ge e^{-(t/a)^2/2}$.

Comment: I feel like this should be the same probability as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2332298/7072 (the first time $W_t\not\in(-a,a)$. However, I get quite different probabilities. E.g. for $a=1$ and $t=2$ your answer gives $P\approx 0.0087$, while that answer is $\approx 0.108$. Am I missing a distinction here?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Using Mathematica, I also get $\approx 0.108$ with my formula. [Here is an online Mathematica compiler which verifies this.](https://tio.run/##jY6xCsIwFADnvK/I2NZXaQtdlC5aXIpF6BheJYpgqGkkvuIgfnu0u4P73XFW8/ViNZuzDqGRlSyzNUA33TfePce9Y@PGbb1T@oh8JLmqJIhWdZNVIESU5nE/JNEMtM5bfavNg705TbOmMuQ@W5aEOiqSYZHHlP5FfqsUI4jXgGmDzZsI4ODNyOrHWI4FAYXwAQ "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: I thought `NormalDistribution[]` took the variance and not the standard deviation :D. That explains it. Thanks!