# Upper bound for $\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t| \right)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $T>0$ be fixed. I am interested in finding upper bounds for the expectations of the following running suprema:
$$
\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t|, \quad \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t|^2.
$$
We can use Doob's maximal inequality for the second term to get
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t|^2\right) \leq 4 \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left(|B_t|^2\right)}_{=t} = 4T.
$$
Is there a straightforward way to bound
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t| \right) \quad ?
$$
Maybe the estimate
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t| \geq x \right) \leq 2\mathbb{P}(|B_T| \geq x)
$$
could be helpful.

---

**EDIT:** Some further progress

Using the estimate above and the fact that the running supremum under question is non-negative, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t| \right) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |B_t| \geq x \right) dx \leq 2 \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(|B_T| \geq x) d x
$$

Comment: It seems that $\sup|B_t| \sim 2|B_T|$, so you can compute analytically its expectation

Comment: you can use Holder inequality to get: $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} |B_t|)\leq \mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} |B_t|^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @NN2 It is true that $\sup B_t \sim 2|B_T|$, but it is **not** true that $\sup_t |B_t|\sim 2|B_T|$. The distribution for $\sup_t |B_t|$ is a [bit more complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3153411/177399).